# How to debug sporadic outbound connection timeouts?

Tags: ssh, timeout

I'm having trouble connecting to my remote host via SSH. I have narrowed the issue down to my local host *only* as other clients make nominal (fast and stable) connections every time.

Attempting to connect to `remotehost.example.net` from `localhost` via SSH will time out all but about 1 out of 10 attempts (it hangs here and then times out):

```
515 chris@localhost ~ $ ssh -vvv remotehost-root
OpenSSH_6.4, OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/chris/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/chris/.ssh/config line 43: Applying options for remotehost-root
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to remotehost.example.net [123.123.123.123] port 12345.
^C
```

`localhost` is an up-to-date Arch system:

```
517 chris@localhost ~ $ uname -a
Linux localhost 3.12.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Thu Nov 21 08:18:42 CET 2013 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And I'm using an SSH config file to alias `remotehost` as follows:

```
521 chris@localhost .ssh $ cat ~/.ssh/config
...
host remotehost-root
  HostName remotehost.example.net
  User root
  Port 12345
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/remotehost-root.id_rsa
...
```

This is a recent problem, but unfortunately I don't recall making changes to anything relevant. I'm not sure what to check.

Maybe it's worth noting that this affects **all** SSH connections (such as git over ssh and `SFTP`) and not just the command line SSH tool.

I don't have any trouble accessing `remotehost.example.net` over any other protocol (e.g. `HTTP`, `HTTPS`, BitTorrent, etc).

The only active/uncommented line in `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` is:

```
ServerAliveInterval 120
```

Where else can I look? What other debug tools can I use (all I can think to do is run `ssh -vvv`)?

I tried running `tcpdump` on remotehost while attempting a connection, but couldn't figure out how to filter the packets from the shell *running* `tcpdump` thus infinite-loop spamming myself out of any useful diagnostics.

---

**UPDATE 1:** Worth noting that I've been able to duplicate this behavior on a second SSH host, as well as an IRC server, thus proving (in my mind) that this is an issue wholly within some config on my local host.

---

**UPDATE 2:** Also worth noting that while my localhost has trouble with these outbound connections, other clients (including on one, and one off, my LAN) have no issues whatsoever to any of the same remote hosts, or any other hosts. Again, leading me to believe that this is solely some config issue within localhost (but maybe I'm wrong?).

---

**UPDATE 3:** I have removed the openssh package (and configs) from localhost and reinstalled, to no avail.

Comment: so if you do: telnet remotehost.example.net 22 it stays conected and says something like "SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9" and stays constant?

Comment: Check the firewall on the remote system.

Comment: @DanilaLadner - Using telnet also times out most times, but when it doesn't I do see `SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.9p1`.

Comment: @MichaelHampton - No iptables rules (input, forward, output are all accepting), ufw is inactive, I haven't installed fail2ban or anything like that. Again, other clients (on and off my LAN) are able to connect flawlessly.

Comment: by default sshd try to resolve the client hosts, try usedns no in sshd_config and reload the sshd service

Comment: @c4f4t0r Other clients on the LAN can connect (see update 2) but I will still try this.

Comment: Is the connection from your localhost SNATed when connecting to the remote host?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A timeout could happen if you have a high cpu load on your local machine, i had that issue sometimes a few years ago. My Backup process back then did eat my IO + cpu.

As the server i connected to was GPRS and therefor slow by design i did not immediately think of the local host as a problem.

Additionally you might as you said have a limit of connections you are able to use to.

personally i would check the packets with something like wireshark.

Comment: Not a bad thought, but the load on localhost is very low. I am running quite a bit of network-connected software, however. I'll have to look into that.

Comment: This did it. It's not immediately obvious to me which process was the biggest offender, but I do [did] have many networking processes running; when I stop them all, the timeout issue goes away, and I can selectively re-enable them and after a certain threshold (again, still working to find out exactly what) the issue reappears. So it looks like there is some local limit on open TCP connections, connection attempts, collisions opening up random high ports, I'm not sure.

Comment: @Chris Are you DS-Lite or behind NAT?  This could be the culprit, because of a full NAT/Translation table (Quota!) on the router or on ISP-level.  Then it is not local but just the number of open connections.  Others perhaps have less connections and hence are below their connection limit on the routers involved.

Answer (score 4):

1) Do you have GSSAPIAuthentication enabled? Try setting that to "no" in /etc/ssh/sshd_config

2) Have you checked if this is a DNS lookup issue? Try adding the destination host and its ip address to /etc/hosts and retry your ssh connect

3) To do your tcpdump, you can use the following:

```
tcpdump -n "port 22 and dst <ip address of destination host>"
```

4) Can you post the full output of the -vvv debug? Or was that it? Can you show what it says after the timeout?

On any occasion where it hangs, you can also simply do `netstat -an | grep <ip of remote host>` and if the "State" field is "SYN_SENT" then you know it's being blocked on some level.

Comment: I often try to run `tcpdump` on as many hosts along the packets' path as possible and compare their output.  That can help you tell where things are going wrong.  At the very least, running `tcpdump -n port 22 and src <source IP address>` will tell you whether the remote host is seeing the same things as what your client is sending.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try changing the IP address of the client?  Could it be that the LAN firewall is blocking or throttling some of the SSH traffic coming from that specific address?

Comment: I posted a second update. Short version: for what it's worth, another client on the same LAN (indeed, same subnet) can connect to the same remote hosts (even using straight copies of the same ~/.ssh/config and id_rsa files) with no trouble. That said, I haven't yet checked the router (for that reason) but to be complete will do so.